# Get total number of indices in elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I know how to get the total number of documents using the [Count AP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)I, But I need to know total number of indices present in my ES cluster and couldn't find a way to get it.

P.S :- I know about `_cat/indices?v` API but I just need the total count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
GET /_cat/indices
```

It will return you all indices in your cluster in format like this

```
green open .monitoring-kibana-7-2020.12.09      YWHXyIEfSoqxiv6E6Q8uzg 1 1   8639      0   5.6mb   2.8mb
green open question_autocomplete                NgaQwtmjRQ6rEUJwyFQfGw 1 1  15366      3   6.7mb   3.3mb
green open a302abbe-b6e4-4486-b24c-4399f4800e4c mu4IMit4S_Oml5CDjbkZsA 1 1   1705      0 227.3mb 113.3mb
```

Another option is to use cluster stats with filtering

```
GET _cluster/stats?filter_path=indices.count
```

Comment: I know this API but I just want `count`

Comment: @java-dev ok, I've added another option with cluster/stats

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do this programmatically, you may be able to use this:

```
GET /_stats
```

In the response, there is an "indices" key, and you could take a count of all indices contained within it.

Or a count from this (which actually uses an array so may be easier to get a count):

```
GET /_cat/indices?format=json&h=index
```

Answer (score 0):

[`jq` to the rescue](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)... You can pipe the results of the `_cat/indices` query with `jq` in order to find out the count of indexes:

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?format=json' | jq length
```

This is going to give you the single number you're looking for

Comment: i hv to use `curl`, is there is way to do it using postman or simple. GET call in browser ??

Comment: In Postman, you could switch to the `Tests` tab and use the following script `pm.reponse.json().length` in order to know the length of the indexes array